# Why is libtool failing here?

Tags: c++, installation, clang, clang++, libtool-xcode

I am installing HEALPix (c++ version) using clang and when it comes to a libtool command, the process crashes:

```
#  creating library /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/osx_clang/lib/libhealpix_cxx.a
libtool -static -o -v /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/osx_clang/lib/libhealpix_cxx.a
#followed by a long list of object files being archived
libtool: can't open file: /Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/osx_clang/lib/libhealpix_cxx.a (No such file or directory)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/libtool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/libtool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make[1]: *** [/Users/keir/Software/Healpix_3.11/src/cxx/osx_clang/lib/libhealpix_cxx.a] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have searched for the meaning and resolution of this problem but there is no solution specific to the files I am using. I was wondering whether anyone could help figure this out?

I am using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) and I have up-to-date Command Line Tools - I have tried to use libtool to make a very simple archive using 2 object files and the same error comes up. I should mention that my gcc and g++ are not working and is a probable source of error - is there a way to force libtool to use clang instead (as a temporary workaround)?

My libtool version is:

```
Apple Computer, Inc. version cctools-590.36
```

Is there a more up-to-date version, perhaps?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: @PaulR Version 6.1 (6A1052d) and I have up-to-date Command Line Tools - I have tried to use libtool to make a very simple archive using 2 object files and the same error comes up. I should mention that my gcc and g++ *are not working* and is a probable source of error - is there a way to force libtool to use clang instead (as a temporary workaround)?

Comment: I wonder if you've broken something in your command line tools, SDK or libraries - it seems that whatever libtool you're running isn't happy with the dylibs you have in /usr/lib.

Comment: I too had a similar problem. I was trying tho compile LLVM. llvm[4]: Fixing LC_ID_DYLIB of ~/Documents/Deepak/llvm3.5/build/Release+Asserts/lib/clang/3.5.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Did you got any solutions ?

Comment: But gcc and g++ are working fine. So they might not be the problem.

Comment: @DeepakRajHR No, I don't have a solution, I'm afraid. But maybe check your libtool version, because the latest cctools is now 862 (or something like that...)?